How do I play the G/Am guitar chord?
I can’t find out how to play the G/Am guitar chord. I’m hoping someone can help me out here!!

G/Am? (scratches head) The notation I know is Chord / Bass tone, but Am isn't a tone. Where did you find that?

There are polychords where one chord is played over the other, but I've never seen them for guitar and I'm not sure a G over Am polychord is even possible on guitar. I'm also curious where you saw this.

@ToddWilcox G/Am is in fact Am11, could be played 530000 or 555557. But to the OP: please provide context, as quite likely it is some error or perhaps non-standard notation.

We really do need a reference for this chord. Am/G is a common enough chord, found in lots of pop and jazz songs, which actually equates to an Am chord, but with a G note as its bass note. In other words, Am7 in 3rd inversion. But have to say, never ever found G/Am in any song or even a reference to it on Google.

@user1079505 I've never played polychords except on piano. I've been assuming that the voicing matters which is why a polychord like this would be written "G/Am" instead of "Am11". If voicing matters, then neither of your suggestions has a complete G triad sounding above a complete Am triad. If voicing doesn't matter, then I stand corrected.

@ToddWilcox no, I don't mean to argue, just throwing ideas. I feel like arranging on guitar frequently requires compromises, but whether they work or not, that depends on the context. Anyway as I started to dig it, I found: 877787 with two triads separated, though in inversions. Then there's also 12-0-10-12-12-10, with both triads in root position, difficult to play, but the bottom note could be a harmonic played with the right hand.

@user1079505 Guitar voicings may be odd but still quite good to hear, we know that. But the point remains: some voicings make sense as long as they're explicitly written. There's no context from the OP, meaning that we can just consider that notation as a "granted polychord", a pianist could theoretically play that as a cluster spanning from G to E, which, interestingly enough, it's not even that bad ;-) (which is relatively obvious, since it's almost the whole diatonic scale). Yet, just like most complex chords, different voicings could change a lot in their results.

Am/G
If you made a mistake writing the "slash" chord where it is chord slash bass, try this...
302010
You could try 302210, but that is too much of a stretch for me. If you play the third string open, it will double the G pitch, which is a chord tone, and it should allow more freedom to stretch your hand.
If you meant a polychord of a G major triad and an A minor triad. There is a question of which should really be on the bottom, but the convention is first chord listed on top, followed by a horizontal bar, second chord on the bottom. For your symbol that's a G chord on top of an Am chord. All six pitches together are a diatonic Am11 chord. A convenient way to play that is...
x02030
That could also be labeled Am(sus4) but the two chord labels are often used synonymously.
Another fingering, a bit trickier, that gets all the pitches but the C is...
x02433
If you wanted to emphasize a stack of fourths sound, a easy fingering is...
x00012
You really need to...

give your source for the chord symbol, or
explain how it fits into what you are playing

Fingerings and voicings don't occur in isolation. You choices depend on what other positions you need to get your fingers to, or choosing a voicing that fits with the rest of the music you are playing.

Assuming like most have so far that the chord you want is an Am/G, not G/Am. Am/G is simply an Am chord with a G note added in the bass. There are several different ways of playing it but the way shown below is one of the easiest and most useful. The A to high E strings form the Am chord and the note on the 3rd fret of the low E is a G. As suggested in comments by @DPenner1 and agreed to by me, the open A is best muted by using the the flesh of the pinky in order to avoid a muddy sounding chord. The chord is still complete since the G string also plays an A.


In many contexts I would probably mute the A string, the whole step clash in the bass can be a little muddy (and the A is already covered on the G string)

@DPenner1 Good call, I would also. I’ll edit and include it in the answer.
